# Renaming a column with strong_migrations enabled - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I need to rename a column in a Rails project that has enabled strong_migrations. Im looking into the [official guide](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#renaming-a-column) and it specified the following steps to doing it:

1. Create a new column.
2. Write to both columns.
3. Backfill data from the old column to the new column.
4. Move reads from the old column to the new column.
5. Stop writing to the old column.
6. Drop the old column.

So as far as I understand I need about 4 PRs to simply change the name of the column.
This PRs would be:

1. Create the migration for the new table and start using the new field.
2. Backfill data and move reads from the old column to the new one.
3. Add `self.ignored_columns = ["some_column"]` to the model and remove the old logic that use that old column.
4. Create the migration to drop off the old column.

It's that right? Or Im missing something and maybe some of this PRs are not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with 3. With ways to migrate the data (a and b)

1. Add the new column and code that will start writing to it. a) Add a worker that will backfill the data after the deploy
2. Change code to start reading the new column and add the old column to ignored columns. b) Backfill the data in a migration before deploy.
3. Remove the old column

Data migration style will depend on the size of your database. If it's small enough, you can do it in the migration during deploy. If it's bigger, you'll have to migrate the data beforehand. Either a worker or a console script. In this case it's still a good idea to have the backfill in a migration as well to ensure the data is migrated everywhere (local db of every developer, staging environments and so on).